# how to add number sequence from 1 to 4 for the row count 1 to 4 and restart sequence again from 1 to 4 when the row count goes 5 to 8

Tags: mysql

I have some session data where the user can sarter the coruse in any session and it will repeat in every session.

example
user 1
started on 2022-01-15 so the data for the user is like blow

1. 2022-01-15
2. 2022-04-15
3. 2022-07-15
4. 2022-10-15
5. 2023-01-15
6. 2023-04-15
7. 2023-07-15
8. 2023-10-15

for this data I need to add some data as below

1. 2022-01-15 session1 year 1
2. 2022-04-15 session2 year 1
3. 2022-07-15 session3 year 1
4. 2022-10-15 session4 year 1
5. 2023-01-15 session1 year 2
6. 2023-04-15 session2 year 2
7. 2023-07-15 session3 year 2
8. 2023-10-15 session4 year 2

Example 2
for this data I need to add some data as below

1. 2021-10-15 session1 year 1
2. 2022-01-15 session2 year 1
3. 2022-04-15 session3 year 1
4. 2022-07-15 session4 year 1
5. 2022-10-15 session1 year 2
6. 2023-01-15 session2 year 2
7. 2023-04-15 session3 year 2
8. 2023-07-15 session4 year 2

How can achive this in MYSQL
I am not getting any idea on this

Comment: ```new_num = 1 + (prev_num MOD 4)```.  Or simply use `QUARTER(date)`.

Comment: What is your MySQL version? Can run `SELECT @@version` or `SELECT version()` to check.

Comment: Hi the version is 8.0.26

Comment: @Akina
the user can start their coruse in any quarter so it is not usefull to add session 1 for users who starts their first session on quarter 2,3,4.

Comment: If so then ``1 + TIMESTAMPDIFF(QUARTER, current_row_date, MIN(date)) MOD 4``

Answer (score 0):

This will work for MySQL from version 8+:

1. We use `MIN(col) OVER (PARTITION BY col)` to get the minimum for each user.
2. Then use `DATEDIFF()` to calculate each row date difference between the session start date and the session date itself.
3. Wrap those query using `COMMON TABLE EXPRESSION (cte)` and use the result from `DATEDIFF()` divide by `365` days.
4. Add `FLOOR()` function to make the above result as single digit and act as a "makeshift group code".
5. Use each user and the result from "makeshift group" as `PARTITION` in `ROW_NUMBER()` function.

This is the final query:

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT userID,
       sessionDate,
       DATEDIFF(sessionDate, MIN(sessionDate) OVER (PARTITION BY userID)) daysFrSstart
FROM mytable)
SELECT userID,
       sessionDate,
       daysFrSstart,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY userID, FLOOR(daysFrSstart/365) 
                            ORDER BY userID, sessionDate) sessionQuarter
  FROM cte;
```

And here's a fiddle with detailed steps and more examples: https://dbfiddle.uk/n6NuYuNL